# regex working in java code but not working in javascript code

Tags: javascript

i have the following regex which is working fine in JAVA code

```
[A-Za-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[A-Za-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[A-Za-z0-9](?:[A-Za-z0-9-]*[A-Za-z0-9])?\\.)+[A-Za-z0-9](?:[A-Za-z0-9-]*[A-Za-z0-9])?
```

but same is not working in the Java script

can any one please tell me the solution for this

thanks Sunny Mate

Comment: Could you post you current javascript code explaining the expected outcome and the actual outcome?

Comment: please use a code block and escape the regex the right way so that it gets shown proper

Answer (score 2):

I'd put the last hyphen from those sets as the first character:

```
Before:
[A-Za-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]
After:
[-A-Za-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~]
```

The hyphen will allow a range of characters. It will be treated as hyphen if it is the first character of the set. Else, it could mean "from '~' until ']'"

But still, it's hard to answer precisely without a precise question.

**EDIT**:
I've tested this expression on a [simple JavaScript RegEx tester](http://alessandrosantos.com.br/lab/er/), and I discovered it is meant to match e-mail addresses. It worked for me after I replaced the double-backslashes `\\` by single ones `\`.

In JavaScript, the following two should work the same:

```
var re = /a\.c/;  
var re = new RegExp("a\\.c");
```

But the second one requires double back-slashes because it is enclosed in a string, which requires escaping. If all else fails, check [Mozilla Developer Center](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

But, again, it's impossible to give a precise answer without a precise question. What's more, when you try to improve your question, it's more likely that you will find your bug.

Answer (score 0):

Regular Expression is slightly different in each programming language, please reference the manual/document.